# Limiting customer purchases

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Customers can have many purchases but can only purchase that item once, however that same item can be purchased by up to 10 other customers. Is there a way I can implement this in my database design, or is it something I must do on the application side?

Comment: This sounds like something that should absolutely be done on the application side.

Comment: You *can* use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) to enforce that logic within the database, but you would be wise to also perform such checks within the application in order that you can provide better feedback to the user.

Comment: Put that in your application logic layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can possibly be implemented in your DB, but it is a bad idea. Reasons:

- Your DB is there to represent data, not to represent business rules
  governing the use of the data. Keeping the data representation
  separate from the business logic allows you to be more flexible e.g.
  by switching to a new database if you need to.
- Code that puts data
  into and out of the DB may try to violate those rules, so you need to
  either prevent the option being presented to the customer in the first place, or display
  a properly formatted error. Both of these situation require the code
  to have knowledge of whatever business rules would be
  represented in the database, so there's no point putting them in the
  DB in the first place. Just write them once in your code.

One solution would be to create some sort of purchase manager object which controls whether or not a purchase can go ahead, encapsulating the business logic all in one place.